# validates :title, presence: true is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, model

I just made a new rails file, in my model file ( called `project.rb`) I have the following validation in place:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :title, presence: true

end
```

I have three attributes: title, description, and due_date. However, when I jump into my terminal and type in a description and due date (and no title) and hit save, it works!

I don't understand why.

```
 > p.description="lksdf"     ( add description )
"lksdf"
 > p.due_date="kldf"          ( add due_date )
"kldf"

 > p.save
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN

   (4.6ms)  COMMIT
true

2.2.0 :077 > Project.all
  Project Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects"
+----+-------------+-----------------+-----------------+----------------+-----------------+
| id | title       | description     | due_date        | created_at     | updated_at      |
+----+-------------+-----------------+-----------------+----------------+-----------------+
| 1  | 1st project | this is my f... | in a weeks time | 2015-01-15 ... | 2015-01-15 1... |
| 2  | 2ndproj     | 2nd slfajlsj... | next year       | 2015-01-15 ... | 2015-01-15 1... |
| 3  | 3rdsdlfk    | kdlajdflks;af   | never haha      | 2015-01-15 ... | 2015-01-15 1... |
| 4  | 4th title   | lasdj           | 2045            | 2015-01-15 ... | 2015-01-15 1... |
| 5  | fifth title | ldksajf         | never aaja      | 2015-01-15 ... | 2015-01-15 1... |
| 6  |             | klsaf           | slkadf          | 2015-01-15 ... | 2015-01-15 1... |
| 7  |             | kjldsfds        |                 | 2015-01-15 ... | 2015-01-15 1... |
| 8  |             | aljbsfalkjsdf   |                 | 2015-01-15 ... | 2015-01-15 1... |
| 9  |             | lksdf           | kldf            | 2015-01-15 ... | 2015-01-15 1... |
+----+-------------+-----------------+-----------------+----------------+-----------------+
9 rows in set
```

Comment: What does the entire model look like?

Comment: Did you `reload!` or restart the console?

Answer (score 2):

I am able to figure out what was the problem.

I didn't save my file properly before re-running my server, problem solved!